# Kernel and image of this linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I dont know how i can solve this problem, if you know, please, explain me... help...: Consider in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the following linear transformations, $f_{\alpha}:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ that in the standar basis it is given by: $$\begin{bmatrix}cos(\alpha) & sin(\alpha)\\ -sin(\alpha)& cos(\alpha)\end{bmatrix} \alpha\ \epsilon\ \mathbb{R}$$ 
Finding its kernel and its image of that linear tranformations. Finding $\alpha$ to $f_{\alpha}(\vec{v})=\lambda \vec{v}$ to the equiation have no trivial solution. $\lambda\ \epsilon\ \mathbb{R}$

Comment: What is the determinant of the matrix?

Comment: $f_\alpha$ is just a clockwise rotation of the plane by the angle $\alpha.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_{\alpha}$ is the rotation matrix. You can see that que $||f_{\alpha}(v)||=||v||$, therefore $f_{\alpha}(v)=\lambda v$ when $\alpha = 2n\pi, n\in Z$ and $\lambda = 1$, i.e when $f_{\alpha}= id$ and also you can see that the kernel es $v=0$ and image is $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is rotation by $\alpha$, counterclockwise. The rotation is surjective - given a vector, you consider it rotated by $\alpha$ *clockwise*, and then apply the rotation, you'll get the initial vector. If $R: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ is the rotation, we have: $$2 = \dim\ker R + \dim\,{\rm ran}\, R \implies \begin{cases} \dim \ker R = 0 \\ \dim\,{\rm ran}\, R = 2\end{cases},$$ hence $\ker R = \{0\}$ and ${\rm ran}\,R = \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: It's a clockwise rotation for $\alpha > 0.$